# Memory Mapping a file in POSIX

Tags: c, posix, mmap

When memory mapping files in a `POSIX` system, do we need to keep the file-descriptor open till we're done with the `mmap`ed memory block (and `close` it after we `munmap`) or can (should?) we `close` the file descriptor once `mmap` succeeds? Both seem to work on my Linux system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Open Group standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html)

> The mmap() function shall add an extra
>   reference to the file associated with
>   the file descriptor fildes which is
>   not removed by a subsequent close() on
>   that file descriptor. This reference
>   shall be removed when there are no
>   more mappings to the file.

Comment: ...which means "No, you do not need to keep the file descriptor open while the file is mapped.".